# jQuery Animsition Plugins not working with Angular Router

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the Animsition plugin working in an Angular project. The loader is stuck and the view doesn't load.

```
$(".animsition").animsition({
        inClass: 'fade-in',
        outClass: 'fade-out',
        inDuration: 1500,
        outDuration: 800,
        linkElement: 'a:not([target="_blank"]):not([href^=#], [class^="image-link"])',
        loading: true,
        loadingParentElement: 'body', //animsition wrapper element
        loadingClass: 'animsition-loading',
        unSupportCss: ['animation-duration',
            '-webkit-animation-duration',
            '-o-animation-duration'
        ],
        overlay: false,

        overlayClass: 'animsition-overlay-slide',
        overlayParentElement: 'body'
    });
```

Comment: create a fiddle or plunker for that